# Fast functional method for multiplying duplication numbers in a large list

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, functional-style

Consider a list of symbols:

```
mySet = {a, b, b, c, a, b, c, d};
```

I would like to form the product of duplication numbers.  In the example above, I have 2 `a`'s, 3 `b`'s, 2 `c`'s and 1 `d`.  So the result I need is $2\times3\times2\times1 = 12$.

Here is what I came up with.  I use `Tally` to count up the duplication numbers, and then multiply all the numbers which are in the second part.

```
duplProd[stuff_List] := Times @@ Transpose[Tally[stuff]][[2]]
```

And I get the expected.

```
duplProd[mySet]
(* 12 *)
```

But I have enormous lists (like with 1000 to 10000 entries). Is there a way to achieve this result that runs faster?  I know that I must avoid `Part` since it makes things go slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 10:

```
Times @@ Counts @ mySet
(* 12 *)
```

Other versions:

```
Times @@ Length /@ Gather @ mySet
(* 12 *)

Times @@ Length /@ Split @ Sort @ mySet
(* 12 *)
```

Some timings:

```
testdata=RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a","z"],{10000}];
Times @@ Transpose[Tally[testdata]][[2]]//AbsoluteTiming//First 
(*  0.00170  *)
Times@@Counts@testdata//AbsoluteTiming//First
(*  0.00171  *)
Times@@Length/@Gather@testdata//AbsoluteTiming//First
(*  0.00078  *)
Times@@Length/@Split@Sort@testdata//AbsoluteTiming//First
(*  0.00187  *)
Times @@ Last /@ Tally@testdata//AbsoluteTiming//First
(*  0.00170  *)
Times @@ Tally@testdata // Last//AbsoluteTiming//First
(*  0.00170  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

These are marginally faster than yours:

```
mySet = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 10000];

Times @@ Last /@ Tally@mySet
```

or:

```
Times @@ Tally@mySet // Last
```